# How does the GPL apply to code in Blender files? (e.g. Drivers)

Tags: python, scripting

It's known that any Python script running inside Blender must be GPLv2+ compatible ***, See the [GPL FAQ](http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfInterpreterIsGPL), but what about driver expressions? Does this mean all my Blend files have to be GPL as well?

What are the implications for having Python code inside a `.blend` file?

*** *if it is to be redistributed*

Comment: Can you link to where the GPL requirement for scripts is?

Comment: @David: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfInterpreterIsGPL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**, the GPL applies to drivers too.

Just as the GPL applies to addons, it applies to drivers *(any scripts running inside of Blender)*. However this doesn't automatically everything you do in that blend file is suddenly GPL.

Consider:

- In many cases drivers on their own don't constitute an **original work**, Obviously you can't copyright `1 + 1`, `rot / pi` or other simple expressions.
  *Exactly what is original enough to be copyrighted isn't totally clear and depends on local laws.*
- In the case where the client/customer has the blend file, they can see the driver expressions *anyway*, and use them, however drivers are rarely useful on their own, typically they are only valuable because of their use within a rig and data they reference (the rig, objects etc).
- In many cases, the deliverable content from a project isn't a blend file, The finished work may be image / video / exported-model, therefor there is no need to distribute the blend file, a driver can be treated as *in house software*.

---

So the main case this prohibits are:

- If you made a rig and wanted to charge licensing fee's for using the drivers.
  *While this remains possible, you would have to use a GPL compatible license for the drivers.*
- If you give a blend file to someone, you could **not** prohibit them from reusing or sharing a driver-expression in that blend file.

In practice, the drivers in a blend file are plain-text anyway, and not all that useful on their own.

---

**But might mixing the scripts with the `.blend` file data, also make the blend file GPL?**

It's worth looking into this more, however Wordpress lets images in a theme be exempt from the GPL. (Where the theme may contain code & data, this is a precedent where the data is exempt while the code isn't).
http://wordpress.org/news/2009/07/themes-are-gpl-too/

---

*Obligatory - **I am not a lawyer** disclaimer, however this is how the GPL applies as I understand it @ideasman42*

Answer (score 0):

> Just as the GPL applies to addons, it applies to drivers (any scripts running inside of Blender).

I disagree.
You are taking the statement too literally imho.
Imho, one thing is the container (Blender) and one thing is the content(the blender file, so to say).
The GPL applies to every script/source you add to the container, not the content.
For the content, what applies is the license related to it, be it texture, model, drivers, and so on, you agreed with Blender Foundation when using Blender.

This is very similar to what game engines do - having your animation code written in a script in Unity it does not mean your game becomes Unity property or its license applies it (otherwise, probably no one is going to use it...) what applies is the license for the content you agreed to when using Unity.
Of course I'm no lawyer so I can be wrong... ;-)

Comment: The thing is once you use Python in Blender there is no clear differentiation between addon/driver/exporter.. etc - it's all just Python code. You could make a driver that makes an interface to blender if you really wanted... or implemented a 3D application through the driver. This is why we can't treat drivers as special cases.

Comment: I don't see drivers as special case - I set a clear definition between content and container. So, I don't see just python code; I see python code separated by use cases. One use case for the container(Blender) one for the content(the blender file, to be clear). This seems to be supported by the will of B.F. to let the user own the content. If this is not clear, it means there's s.t. wrong about policies, s.t. B.F. should strive to clear, in its own interest and for the interest of the users...

Comment: This way, you can have s.t. like: a) use a driver for creating an interface to Blender (extending Blender, so GPL), and b) use a driver for managing animation (blender file, user ownership), and so on... it really depends on use case...

Comment: re: *"I set a clear definition between content and container"* - you may, but this doesn't mean a license does.